# Ground Prong on Laptop Charger

Tags: electrical

Recently, the ground prong on my laptop charger came off and got stuck in the wall.  I have since retrieved the prong. My question is whether there is a way I could put the prong back into the Charger.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this the cord that goes from the charger brick to the wall?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about repairing an electrical cord, not about Home Improvement. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: @NiallC. Maybe it can be migrated to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @ChrisM.They'd close it too.

Comment: Unfortunate.  To answer the question anyway, you can't reinsert the prong into the cord, but you can cut off the plug and buy a new 3-prong plug from the hardware store and install that on the end.

Comment: I was answering this when it was closed, I disagree that it is off topic we see these questions all the time. You can not just put the prong back in but you can purchase a cord cap at an electrical or big box store and replace the end. Make sure to verify the hot and neutral are on the correct lugs (sometimes the neutral wire will be silver and the hot copper, other times the insulation inside the cord will be white or blue for neutral  and black or blue for hot) If there are no colors you will need to verify the connections with an ohm meter or continuity checker on the existing plug.

Comment: I'm assuming this would be fine if it was a fridge or washing machine instead of a laptop -- despite the problem, dangers, and repair being basically identical? Voting to reopen also.  Example similar: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61388/replacing-an-electrical-cord https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18243/how-can-i-fix-chewed-through-wires

Comment: In a lot of cases the cord from the power brick to the wall is removable and has a fairly common end type at the brick side. If this is the case for you, you can get a fairly cheap replacement of that portion of the cord at Amazon, eBay, Monoprice, etc.

Comment: @EdBeal exactly.  If the neutral wire is not otherwise marked, look for one side of the cord having subtle ribs on it.  That must be neutral according to NEC.

Comment: Forgot about the ribbed cords +